# Error when editing a question while there is another editing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, error-message

I tryed to edit a question an got this error:
[image: Error_picutre]
Shouldn't there be another way to display this?
Maybe with an popup?

Comment: The edit link should have been disabled but if between your click being send and just before the page started rendering another user submitted his edit you'll get in this state I guess.

Comment: I think it's ugly.

Comment: @mmking ... thats what I mean :)

Comment: This reminded me the old _Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days_ error.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed; there is now a red popup box.

Comment: Well, you answered it five years and three days later, interesting!!